# URL append with previous URL

Tags: django

In one app `name: loginsystem` I have

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('logout/', views.UserLogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('profile/', views.ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
    path('login/', views.UserLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('password_change/', views.UserPasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='password_change'),
    path('password_reset/', views.UserPasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset_done/', views.UserPasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.UserPasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password-reset-complete/', auth_view.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

In the other app of urls file I was trying to include these urls and wrote this line

```
path('accounts/', include('loginsystem.urls')),
```

but when i'm trying to access login url from html it appends with previous url like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/#/accounts/login/
```

it adds `#` sign before the url
my html

```
<a href="#{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-warning">Login</a>
```

this html not in loginsystem app this is in other app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you wrote a hash (`#`) in front of the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url). You should remove the leading hash:

```
<!--    ↓ no hash -->
<a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-warning">Login</a>
```